# How to count multiple fields with group by another field in solr

Tags: solr

I have solr document which is like below.

agentId : 100
          emailDeliveredDate : 2018-02-08,
          emailSentDate : 2018-02-07
agentId : 100
          emailSentDate : 2018-02-06
agentId : 101
          emailDeliveredDate : 2018-02-08,
          emailSentDate : 2018-02-07

**I need a result like below.**

agentId : 100
          emailDeliveredDate : 1,
          emailSentDate : 2
agentId : 101
          emailDeliveredDate : 1,
          emailSentDate : 1

In mysql it will be :
 **select count(emailDeliveredDate),count(emailSentDate) group by agentId;**

I need help in solr for this.

Comment: Is each `(agentId, emailDeliveredDate, emailSentDate)` separate documents?

Comment: No. One document contains 1 agentId and emailDeliveredDate, emailSentDate.  Sorry I do not know how to do formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not get any way in Solr which can help me. So I used facet with pivot which gave me half results. Rest half calculation I did in Java.